# PHP scripts do not render in browser

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to install and test a development server on my Windows 7 laptop following [this tutorial](http://www.bicubica.com/apache-php-mysql/index.php).

However when I ran the script on the browser as:

```
http://localhost/info.php
```

I only got:

[image: PHP source]

Does anyone have any pointers for fixing this?

Comment: Could you add the error log from `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log`? Have you restarted Apache after enabling PHP?

Comment: yes, I did restart apache.

Comment: Could you attach your error.log file?

Comment: Give "[apache is not interpreting .PHP files](http://serverfault.com/questions/286882/apache-is-not-interpreting-php-files)" a read on Server Fault. You could also try using an automated WAMP package like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to tell Apache to, instead of sending the text of `.php` files to the client directly, to instead send them to a script interpreter.

So it sounds like things messed up where you had to [add your PHP interpreter as a handler.](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php)  Did you perform step 5 of your tutorial correctly?  Also, if I'm not mistaken, newer versions of Apache don't use `httpd.conf` for any configuration information but the base configuration file is `apache2.conf` or something like that.

Comment: on the tutorial, the last line for modifying the php handler is PHPIniDir "C:/windows", and for the link you provided, I found: PHPIniDir "C:/php". Which one is correct?

Comment: I'd search your system for `php.ini` and, wherever it is, use that path.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is probably not installed correctly or you haven't installed apache with php support. Are you building all this from source?

**What's happening?**

Right now you have a php file which, when navigated to, doesn't display results. Instead it displays it's code just like if it was a simple text file. This is cause by PHP not being able to parse the file and interpret it as code. Therefore your browser sees it as text and displays it as such. The comment below (*by horatio*) outlines what specifically needs to be present for PHP and Apache to work nicely together. Installing PHP isn't the only thing needed, you need to modify apache's config file to tell it how to handle .php files.

Comment: Hi Max, I think apache is ok, and I installed it using the MSI, windows installer package.

Comment: There are two places to check for PHP installation: 1) apache http.config must be set to load the PHP module. (restart the apache service after enabling) and 2) since you are using a local machine, you can test running the php script via the command line by invoking php.